# Python - How can i create a nested map function based on the number of entries in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, map-function

To put in context. I am trying to put as arguments of a function a timetable of subjects to compare if they are being developed at the same hour. I got a function that compares the schedule of *args as input. The structure of the data and the function is this: (where every 2 digit number means 'day'+'module', so 14 means monday 4th module)

```
data = {'MAT': {1:[21,56,45], #maths 1st sec, 3 times a week:tuesday, friday and thursday)
             2:[23,45,66],
             3:[23,45,65],
             4:[54,38,37],
             5:[23,45,65]},

     'IND': {1:[37,51,44],
             2:[13,14,25],
             3:[78,45,54],
             4:[94,45,37]},

     'ECO': {1:[12,56,42],
             2:[23,54,66],
             3:[69,45,65],
             4:[16,28,35]},

     'REL': {1:[21,56,33],
             2:[68,69,76],
             3:[24,69,87],
             4:[54,48,37]}} 

def set_if2(*args):
    lista = sum(args, [])
    if len(set(lista)) == len(lista):
        return lista
```

Every input must came from a different subject, so I know that if run:

```
TEST = set_if2(X['MAT'][1], X['IND'][1], X['ECO'][2], X['REL'][2])
```

My output is going to be `TEST = [21, 56, 45, 37, 51, 44, 23, 54, 66, 68, 69, 76]`

Which means that if i took those 4 classes, I would have to go to university in those hours. But the results are only possible if there are no time coincidences between classes.

My question is, how can I achieve compare every possible combination picking only one section per subject at a time. I know I can do this by using for loops, but I am looking for the most efficient approach because the original dataset is way bigger than the one of the example. So, I tried using map functions, however, this didn't work, because the amount of nested map functions depends on how many subjects I want to take.

Here is what I'm trying to do for the specific case of taking 4 subjects:

```
def mix_unmatched(Ramo1, Ramo2, Ramo3, Ramo4): 
    p = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: list(map(lambda z: list(map(lambda k: set_if2(Ramo1[x], Ramo2[y], Ramo3[z], Ramo4[k]),Ramo4)), Ramo3)), Ramo2)), Ramo1))
    return p

MIX = mix_unmatched(X['MAT'], X['IND'], X['ECO'], X['REL'])
```

I think my solution must be something like a function that creates nested maps automatically using recursion. But i don't know if that is even possible, so if you come with something else, you are welcome.

I haven't think about the output yet, but i believe that a dataframe or a dict will do the work, something like `{...'MAT-1, IND-3, ECO-1, REL-2' = [21, 56, 45, 37, 51, 44, 23, 54, 66, 68, 69, 76], ...}`. Where the `None` solutions are filtered for being useless.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all possible schedules that are non-colliding. I use recursion to get all possible combinations of subjects:

```
data = {'MAT': {1:[21,56,45], #maths 1st sec, 3 times a week:tuesday, friday and thursday)
             2:[23,45,66],
             3:[23,45,65],
             4:[54,38,37],
             5:[23,45,65]},

     'IND': {1:[37,51,44],
             2:[13,14,25],
             3:[78,45,54],
             4:[94,45,37]},

     'ECO': {1:[12,56,42],
             2:[23,54,66],
             3:[69,45,65],
             4:[16,28,35]},

     'REL': {1:[21,56,33],
             2:[68,69,76],
             3:[24,69,87],
             4:[54,48,37]}}

out = []
for k, v in data.items():
    out.append([])
    for kk in v:
        out[-1].append((k, kk))

def get_schedules(all_data, current_data=[]):
    if len(current_data) == len(data):
        yield current_data

    for idx, d in enumerate(all_data):
        for i in d:
            yield from get_schedules(all_data[idx+1:], current_data + [i])

def is_schedule_possible(data, schedule):
    all_hours = []
    for (subject, idx) in schedule:
        all_hours.extend(data[subject][idx])
    return(len(all_hours) == len(set(all_hours)))

for s in get_schedules(out):
    if (is_schedule_possible(data, s)):
        print(s)
```

Prints:

```
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 2), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 2), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 2), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 2), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 1), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 2), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 3), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 3), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 4), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 1), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 1), ('REL', 4)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 1)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 2)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 3)]
[('MAT', 5), ('IND', 2), ('ECO', 4), ('REL', 4)]
```